# Подсвечивание отступов в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Не так давно я начал работать в Jupyter Notebook. Реализовано ли в нем подсвечивание отступов внутри ячеек с кодом? Например, если имеется множество вложенных блоков с инструкциями,то иногда, чтобы понять что и к какому блоку относится, приходится пролистывать код и напрягать глаза, а это не всегда удобно, когда долго работаешь.

[image: Так выглядит код в Jupyter:]

В том же Notepad++, например, отступы для различных блоков выделены пунктирной линией, что упрощает как читаемость, так и процесс редактирования.
[image: А так в Notepad++:]